# Differentiating $ \arctan (\frac{a+x}{1-ax})- \arctan x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have differentiated $$ \arctan (\frac{a+x}{1-ax})- \arctan x$$ and got zero as the result. I don't really understand why the derivative is zero, I think it's because $ \arctan (\frac{a+x}{1-ax})- \arctan x$ would give a constant as the result hence the first derivative becomes zero, but I cannot find a way to prove that this is the case.

Would anybody explain to me why the first derivative is zero?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\arctan(\dfrac{a+x}{1-ax}) = \arctan{a}+\arctan{x}$$ ;)

---

if you don't know why:

$$\tan(a+b) = \dfrac{\tan a + \tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b} \implies a + b = \arctan \left( \dfrac{\tan a+ \tan b}{1-\tan a \tan b}\right)$$

let's $a =\arctan u$ and $b = \arctan v$ replace and done :)

Comment: @3do But in this case, won't the value of a and b be restricted?

Comment: Yeah, It should be equal in $mod(\pi)$, that means it has another constant.

Answer (score 2):

As 3d0 writes $\arctan \frac{a+x}{1-ax} = \arctan a + \arctan x$.

One way to see this is your calculation that the derivative is $0$, plus the fact that the (constant) difference between $\arctan \frac{a+x}{1-ax}$ and $\arctan x$ must be $\arctan a$ at $x=0$.

You can also see it geometrically, by drawing some right triangles where the base of one is the hypotenuse of the other, and working out that the tangent of the sum of the angles in the shared corner to see
$$ \tan(\alpha+\beta) = \frac {\tan\alpha+\tan\beta }{1+\tan\alpha\, \tan\beta}$$

Essentially this same geometric argument becomes somewhat slicker with complex numbers; there you just observe that
$$ (1+ai)(1+xi) = (1-ax)+(a+x)i$$
so its argument must be $\arctan\frac{a+x}{1-ax}$ (modulo $\pi$).

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=\arctan a$, $\,t=\arctan x$. Then 
$$\frac{a+x}{1-ax}=\frac{\tan u +\tan t}{1-\tan u\tan t}=\tan(u+t)$$
hence $$\arctan\Bigl(\frac{a+x}{1-ax}\Bigr)=\arctan\bigl(\tan(u+t)\bigr)=u+t+k\pi$$
for some $k\in \mathbf Z$, so that $\,\,\arctan\Bigl(\dfrac{a+x}{1-ax}\Bigr)=\arctan a+\arctan x+k\pi$.